# Storing collection of classes that inherit from a base class using Redis & C#

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I'm trying to create a simple event store using C# and [ServiceStack] Redis.

```
public class AggregateEvents
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public List<DomainEvent> Events { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DomainEvent { }

public class UserRegisteredEvent : DomainEvent 
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserPromotedEvent : DomainEvent
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string NewRole { get; set; }
}
```

if I do a `roots.GetAll()` I get an exception because the abstract class could not be instantiated. If I turn the base class into an interface instead, the Events object is null and the objects I stored in there get lost.

Any thoughts?

### Edit 1

No joy using v3.03 and this code:

```
    [Test]
    public void foo()
    {
        var client = new RedisClient("localhost");
        var users = client.GetTypedClient<AggregateEvents>();


        var userId = Guid.NewGuid();

        var eventsForUser = new AggregateEvents
                       {
                           Id = userId,
                           Events = new List<DomainEvent>()
                       };

        eventsForUser.Events.Add(new UserPromotedEvent { UserId = userId });


        users.Store(eventsForUser);

        var all = users.GetAll(); // exception
    }
```

### Edit 2

Also not worked with this approach;

```
    [Test]
    public void foo()
    {
        var userId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var client = new RedisClient("localhost");

        client.As<DomainEvent>().Lists["urn:domainevents-" + userId].Add(new UserPromotedEvent {UserId= userId});


        var users = client.As<DomainEvent>().Lists["urn:domainevents-" + userId];

        foreach (var domainEvent in users) // exception
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try again with the latest version (v3.05+) of the ServiceStack Redis client:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/downloads

The ServiceStack Json Serializer which the client uses has just added support for deserialization of Abstract/interface types which will be in the latest version of the client.

Note: this works by embedding **__type** information into the JSON payload which tells the serializer what concrete class it should deserialize into. It only embeds this information for Abstract/interface/object types. So you when you serialize you will need to cast to the abstract type, e.g:

```
redis.Store((DomainEvent)userPromoEvent);
```

or if adding to a list:

```
redis.As<DomainEvent>().Lists["urn:domainevents"].Add(userPromoEvent);
```

These examples now work as indicated by the newly added [DomainEvents Unit Tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/Issues/DomainEventsTests.cs) :)

```
[Test]
public void Can_Retrieve_DomainEvents()
{
    var userId = Guid.NewGuid();
    var client = new RedisClient("localhost");
    client.FlushAll();

    client.As<DomainEvent>().Lists["urn:domainevents-" + userId].Add(
        new UserPromotedEvent { UserId = userId });

    var users = client.As<DomainEvent>().Lists["urn:domainevents-" + userId];

    Assert.That(users.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));

    var userPromoEvent = (UserPromotedEvent)users[0];
    Assert.That(userPromoEvent.UserId, Is.EqualTo(userId));
}


[Test]
public void Can_from_Retrieve_DomainEvents_list()
{
    var client = new RedisClient("localhost");
    var users = client.As<AggregateEvents>();

    var userId = Guid.NewGuid();

    var eventsForUser = new AggregateEvents
    {
        Id = userId,
        Events = new List<DomainEvent>()
    };

    eventsForUser.Events.Add(new UserPromotedEvent { UserId = userId });

    users.Store(eventsForUser);

    var all = users.GetAll(); 
}
```

Comment: I just grabbed the latest from NUGet, I'll get the binaries from github and try now.

Out of interest, would you recommend storing the Events for a particular user inside of a list or a wrapper object?

Comment: If the events are scoped to a specific user, I would used a separate list e.g. `redis.As<DomainEvent>().Lists["urn:DomainEvent:User:1"].Add(...)`

Comment: worth noting that i can get this to work if i cast all my lists down to object, but not as DomainEvent

Comment: Apologies, can you try v3.05 - as the redis client was using an internal serialization method not patched to support abstract/interface types - it should do so now tho :)